# Stuck vim adventure level 6 Kansas

Tags: vim-adventures

I am unable to find a way to delete the "to" from into word in the last step of level 6. The phrase that said "I think we aren't in kansas...".

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

At the end I solved the puzzle, it took me some time.

Solved : de --> delete the character to the end of word.

I used dw, withouth success